# UILocalNotification - Notification not displaying

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilocalnotification

I'm having issues when trying to schedule a UILocalNotification using the following code:

```
    - (IBAction) createNotification {
    //Just to verify button called the method
    NSLog(@"createNotification");

    NSString *dateString = dateTextField.text;

    NSString *textString = textTextField.text;

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"];
    [formatter setTimeZone: [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];

    NSDate *alertTime = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];

    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    UILocalNotification *notification = [[[UILocalNotification alloc] init] autorelease];
    if(notification){
        notification.fireDate = alertTime;
        notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        notification.repeatInterval = 0;
        notification.alertBody = textString;

        [app scheduleLocalNotification:notification];

        NSLog(@"%@", dateString);
    }
}
```

The code is being called correctly when I press the button and I'm passing in the following date string:

02-12-2012 19:01

- I've also tried

02/12/2012 19:01

to no avail.  (I change the time accordingly depending on the time of testing e.g. 21:06)

Can someone please explain why the local notification isn't displaying?

Thanks in advance,

Jack

Comment: What happens when you do `NSLog(@"%@", alertTime)`?

Comment: could you try the following to replace the scheduleLocalNotification with presentLocalNotificationNow to make sure the local notification is working? which iOS version are you working on?

Comment: did you try to NSLog notification.fireDate to see what time it is showing?

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", notification.fireDate) returns 2012-02-12 20:35:00 +0000 when using the input 02-12-2012 20:35.  Its working now though, but it doesn't fire if the app is active, I'm using notifications to execute a piece of code to store and reset the data in some variables, will the code in the notification still fire if the application is active?  Or should I use another approach?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Local notifications are delivered, but do not display (i.e., no badges, no sounds, no alerts) when the app is running and in the foreground. But the `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` method of your app delegate is called, if you need to react to a local notification in some way.

See the [UILocalNotification class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for details.

Comment: Thanks, but my application isn't calling didReceiveLocalNotification?  Any idea why this might be?  Thanks

Comment: So you're saying that you can schedule a notification, and if the app isn't running you'll see the notification, but if you schedule a notification the same way and the app is running, then `application:didReceiveLocalNotification` isn't getting called?

Comment: Yeh, thats exactly it.  I'm using this:
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif {
    NSLog(@"Notification Received");
}

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea—I just tried something similar on my end and it did work. If a notification shows up when the app isn't active, then `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` should get called when the app is active. You implemented that in your app delegate, right?